# 'uniquely human + noun' vs. 'unique human + noun'?

Tags: usage

I googled and found many '***uniquely human*** **+ noun**' phrases as in *Insights are a uniquely human endeavor*. Do you also use '***unique human*** **+ noun**' phrases? If so, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

“Totally, totally different. Something “uniquely human” is something that applies to humans, but not to monkeys, elephants, electric drills or train stations and other things that are not humans. A “unique human” is a human, different from any other human.